# deleting files on multiple PC's with multiple users with batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to set up a batch program that will go to the different computers on my network (from .txt file) and then delete files from the users on the that PC, and then empty the recycle bin. I've got the second part working so I can delete files from multiple users on a PC, but I can't get it to look at other PC's. I was hoping someone might point out what I'm missing here. Here is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (test.txt) DO (


for /f %%a in ('dir /B /AD C:\Users') do (
REM for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (userlist.txt) do (

    if exist "C:\Users\%%a\" del /S /Q "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data\workspace\logs"
    if exist "C:\Users\%%a\" del /S /Q "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\*"
    if exist "C:\Users\%%a\" del /S /Q "C:\Users\%%a\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files"
)

RD %systemdrive%\$Recycle.Bin /S /Q
)

pause
```

Anybody got any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UNC paths.

```
\\server\sharename\folder\file.ext
```

You can get a list of computers with

```
for /f "skip=3" %A in ('net view ^| findstr /C:"\\"') do Echo %A
```

All computers have a share for admins only called `C$` that is the C drive (and D$ etc). `$` makes it hidden. So

for the local computer via UNC

```
del /S /Q "\\127.0.0.1\C$\User\username\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data\workspace\logs"
```

Also there is no point to `If Exist`, just delete it - it will work or not. If you care if it worked or not you test the return value `If errorlevel 1 echo error`. You are causing extra disk access and network traffic. In programming we do and test not test and do.

You can also run a batch on the other computer.

```
wmic /node:"@Computerlist.txt" process call create "c:\\batchfile.bat"
```

Note `\\`  in paths. `C:\\batcfile.bat` is `C:` on the remote computer. This allows you to only use one for loop in your batchfile. You copy the batch file with copy. Net View can generate the computer list although you have to remove `\\`

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=\" %A in ('net view ^| findstr /C:"\\"') do Echo %A
```